# How to emulate Oracle Java with OpenJDK?

Tags: java

I have a java app, which does not wont to work:

```
Please install Java JRE 1.7.0_45 or a more recent version
```

I think it checks java version and vendor. Does openJDK have special option to emulate vendor. I don't want to install Oracle Java.

Here is my output of `java -version`:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_74"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_74-b02)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.74-b02, mixed mode)
```

---

## **Not a cool solution but works**

I have installed Oracle JRE near OpenJDK. On Manjaro (Arch) Linux it is very simple

```
yaourt -S jre
```

After instalation complete it will ask you to select default java. `archlinux-java status` shows installed Java Machines. I have written litle script to run my capricious app with oracle jre:

```
#!/bin/sh
## Get first JRE from 
jrepath=$(archlinux-java status | grep 'jre' -m1 )
## remove spaces
jrepath=$(echo $jrepath | grep -v -e '^$')
## Compose full path
jrepath="/usr/lib/jvm/$jrepath/bin/java"
## Check if it works DEBUG ${jrepath} -version
${jrepath} -jar path/to/STM32CubeMX
```

In addition I wanted to run app from the folder where script is:

```
## Where is script
pushd `dirname $0` > /dev/null
SCRIPTPATH=`pwd -P`  ## -P to resolve symlinks
popd > /dev/null

${jrepath} -jar $SCRIPTPATH/STM32CubeMX
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, OpenJDK doesn't do that.  Each has a vendor property to identify itself.

The value itself is stored within the JAR-files, e.g., as part of the manifest (see [Oracle's documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/versioning/spec/versioning2.html) for instance).  Since the JAR-files are signed, and the API generally prohibits you from changing a system property, there is little to be done to change the version.

Further reading:

- [How can I tell whether Java is Sun / Oracle / OpenJDK? [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10900579/how-can-i-tell-whether-java-is-sun-oracle-openjdk)
- [System Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html)

Answer (score 0):

If your app is looking or Oracle's Java, have you considered that it might be for a reason? If you think that the java version really doesn't matter, you can write a script front end to your java and have it imitate the Oracle java when the version was asked. But I am quite sure version will not be the only thing your app will be checking and you will find yourself writing a very very complex script to filter a lot of different things. It is an idea but I personally do not suggest implementing it.

Comment: But I am quite sure **that** non-complicated app would work. And problem is only with Java version checker, which does not expect to see `OpenJDK`